# Python 3, find nearest timedate value

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I hope to find help here, I am new to python and I want to extract time from 2 different nc file with different time structures.
The first nc file stored time and date information as:

```
year: 2009
month: 10
day: 12
hour: 20
minute: 10
second: 4.0
```

and the second nc file time and date is in "unix epoch time" format for n event (i.e, this nc file contains several timedate information in float64 time(n_event))

What I want to do is to find nearest time from the second nc file to the first nc file time.

I have tried this code for the first nc file:

```
    #time
hour=(nc.__dict__['hour'])
minute=(nc.__dict__['minute'])
second=(nc.__dict__['second'])
    #time= hour,minute,second
time= str(hour)+':'+str(minute)+':'+str(second)

    #date
year_nc=(nc.__dict__['year'])
month_nc=(nc.__dict__['month'])
day_nc=(nc.__dict__['day'])
date_nc= year_nc,month_nc,day_nc
#solved-not used

date_nc_arr = np.array(date_nc)
time_nc_arr = np.array(time)

time_nc_arr
date_nc_arr


full_date_nc_arr=[date_nc_arr,time_nc_arr]
full_date_nc_arr
```

and I get

```
[array([2009,   10,   12], dtype=int32), array('20:10:4.0', dtype='<U9')]
```

and for the second nc file I did:

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime


import datetime 
from netCDF4 import Dataset,num2date 

t_unit = nc2.variables['time'].units # get unit  
t_cal = nc2.variables['time'].calendar
tvalue = num2date(timess,units = t_unit,calendar = t_cal)
str_time = [i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for i in tvalue]


str_time = list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S"), str_time))
print(str_time)
```

and the output is something like: (I just paste some of the time here)

```
['2009-10-12 09:19:25', '2009-10-12 09:24:15', '2009-10-12 09:25:03', '2009-10-12 09:26:37', '2009-10-12 09:31:48', '2009-10-12 09:36:13', '2009-10-12 09:40:46', '2009-10-12 09:41:28', '2009-10-12 09:42:13', '2009-10-12 09:46:14', '2009-10-12 09:47:18', '2009-10-12 09:54:58', '2009-10-12 10:03:07', '2009-10-12 10:09:10', '2009-10-12 10:14:54', '2009-10-12 10:15:34', '2009-10-12 10:16:49', '2009-10-12 10:18:29', '2009-10-12 10:18:59', '2009-10-12 10:20:13', '2009-10-12 10:26:12', '2009-10-12 10:26:14', '2009-10-12 10:32:02', '2009-10-12 10:34:28', '2009-10-12 10:34:42', '2009-10-12 10:35:34', '2009-10-12 10:36:30', '2009-10-12 10:40:35', '2009-10-12 10:47:22', '2009-10-12 10:56:07', '2009-10-12 10:57:02', '2009-10-12 10:59:33', '2009-10-12 11:00:26', '2009-10-12 11:14:17', '2009-10-12 11:14:55', '2009-10-12 11:21:07', '2009-10-12 11:27:10', '2009-10-12 11:27:39', '2009-10-12 11:36:08', '2009-10-12 11:36:58', '2009-10-12 11:40:28', '2009-10-12 11:42:02', '2009-10-12 11:46:35', '2009-10-12 11:48:31', '2009-10-12 11:50:13', '2009-10-12 11:52:06']
```

but when I try to find the nearest timedate value of the first nc file to the second nc file:

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

array = str_time
value = full_date_nc_arr

print(find_nearest(array, value))
```

I get several different errors like:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (463,) (6,)

I will really appreciate it if anyone can give me a solution or better approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have date/time data, then use a datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime
t1 = datetime(
    nc.year, nc.month, nc.day,
    nc.hour, nc.minute, nc.second
)
```

That's all it takes.  If you really do have a Unit time_t value, that's

```
t2 = datetime.fromtimestamp( epoch )
```

Now you have `datetime` objects you can compare directly.  I'm not sure `numpy` is really required for this, although it does understand `datetime` values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, initially I got this error for t1: 
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float, I tried to remove nc.second (as the second value has a decimal), and it gaves me the t1. However I need the second for my comparision, is there anyway to remove this error?